# Exit If and Next For

Tags: excel, vba

I have a for next loop with an if statement. If the "If statement" is true then exit the if and next for.  Here is the code:  What I want is if Rng1 is not with in Range1 then goto the next rng1.  I seems like a simple solution, but I cannot figure is out.  Thank you in advance.

```
Sub me_test()

Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select Your Range :", xtitledID, Range1.Address, Type:=8)

    For Each Rng1 In Range1
        If Intersect(Rng1, Range("B7:B15")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Not within the perscribed range." & vbCr & "Please click OK to continue."
        Else
            Rng1.Value = "Good"
        End If
    Next

MsgBox "All Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do - *"What I want is if Rng1 is not with in Range1 then goto the next rng1."* - your code is already doing that, no? It sounds like you need an `Exit For` somewhere? Also, for the sanity of yourself and others, you should really use more descriptive variables than `Rng1` and `Range1` - talk about confusing! :)

Comment: Sorry, if rng1 is not in range1 then goto the next rng1. untimatly what I am trying to do is eliminate the possibility of the user selecting a cell or range of cells outside of the defined range, range1.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub me_test()

    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range

    Set Range1 = Application.Selection

    Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select Your Range :", xtitledID, _
                                       Range1.Address, Type:=8)

    Set Range1 = Application.Intersect(Range1, ActiveSheet.Range("B7:B15"))

    If Range1 is nothing then
         MsgBox "No valid cells selected!"
    else
         Range1.Value = "Good"
    end if 

End Sub
```

Comment: A valid intersection between two ranges doesn’t ensure one of them is completely contained in the other

Comment: I know that, but that wasn't a requirement in the OP's question.

Comment: I’m referring to her comment _”untimatly what I am trying to do is eliminate the possibility of the user selecting a cell or range of cells outside of the defined range, range1”_

Comment: I was following the general logic of the code the OP posted, and "What I want is if Rng1 is not with in Range1 then goto the next rng1" - seemed like the aim was to only process cells within the desired range.  The whole thing is a little unclear though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It works on my end

```
Sub me_test()

    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim rngIntr As Range

    Set Range1 = Application.Selection
    Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select Your Range :", xtitledID, Range1.Address, Type:=8)


    For Each Rng1 In Range1
        Set rngIntr = Intersect(Rng1.Cells, Range("B7:B15").Cells)
        If rngIntr Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Not within the perscribed range." & vbCr & "Please click OK to continue."
        Else
            Rng1.Value = "Good"
        End If
        Set rngInr = Nothing
    Next

    Set Range1 = Nothing
    Set Rng1 = Nothing

    MsgBox "All Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this: Only show the "Not within..." Msgbox if **none** of the selected cells are within the desired range. Otherwise continue to iterate through the selection and write *Good* in every cell that is intersecting with the desired range.

```
Sub me_test2()

Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select Your Range :", xtitledID, Range1.Address, Type:=8)

If Intersect(Range("B7:B15"), Range1) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not within the perscribed range." & vbCr & "Please click OK to continue."
Else
    For Each Rng1 In Range1
        If Not Intersect(Rng1, Range("B7:B15")) Is Nothing Then
            Rng1.Value = "Good"
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "All Done"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
Sub me_test()
    Dim rng1 As Range

    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select Your Range :", xtitledID, Selection.Address, Type:=8)

    If Union(rng1, Range("B7:B15")).Address =  Range("B7:B15").Address Then 
        rng1.Value = "Good"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not within the perscribed range." & vbCr & "Please click OK to continue."
    End If

    MsgBox "All Done"

End Sub
```

You may also want to check for a valid used range selection:

```
Sub me_test()
    Dim rng1 As Range

    Do 
        Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select Your Range :", xtitledID, Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    Loop While rng1 Is Nothing

    If Union(rng1, Range("B7:B15")).Address =  Range("B7:B15").Address Then 
        rng1.Value = "Good"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not within the perscribed range." & vbCr & "Please click OK to continue."
    End If

    MsgBox "All Done"

End Sub
```